# How to send OBIEE report to an FTP server using OBIEE Agent?

Tags: linux, ftp, obiee

BI Publisher allows sending BI Publisher reports (created using a Data Model) to an FTP server, but there is no built-in functionality to allow sending OBIEE reports to an FTP server.

I've found some resources where people have used Server Scripts using a Visual Basic file to save the report to a directory then send that file to an FTP destination:

https://wapcobiee.wordpress.com/2015/08/27/obiee-send-content-to-ftp-server-network-folder/

However, this only works for environments where the BI server is installed on a Windows machine.

I need a Linux solution. Has anyone successfully implemented this for a Linux system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a EJB application couple of years back to get it working. You will have to deploy the EJB in the application server (like WebLogic) and use it to export to FTP server.

https://github.com/rvijaysubs/obiee/tree/master/ftpreports

I do not remember the exact steps, so you'll have to play with it.